# How can I let applications start up automatically while booting?

Tags: startup

Is there an easy way to let applications start automatically, like in Windows: simply put a link in the autostart folder, or enter the path and the name of the executable in the registry?

Answer (score 17):

### Adding applications to autostart using the GUI

Starting applications automatically in elementary OS is as easy as in Windows, if not even easier.

1. Open *System Settings*
2. Click at *Applications* and switch to *Startup*
3. Click at the + button in the lower left corner
4. Choose your application or start typing it's name in the upper textfield. If it's a command, you would like to start, type it in the lower textfield

[image]

---

### Manually adding Applications to autostart

All autostart entries are being stored in `~/.config/autostart`. The entries are basically `.desktop` files.
This is an example of my Insync autostart entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Insync
GenericName=Insync
Comment=Launch Insync
Icon=insync
Categories=Network;
Exec=insync start
TryExec=insync
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=3
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

The only difference are the last two lines. `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay` adds a delay in seconds, and `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` decides if this application is enabled or disabled as autostart entry.

Instead of using the GUI, you can copy the `.desktop` file of your desired autostart application from `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` and add the two missing lines by hand.

Answer (score 7):

Sure there is!

1. Open `System Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Startup` tab.
2. Click on the `+` icon in the lower left corner.
3. Find the app you want.

Done!

Comment: damn... I was too slow :)

Comment: thnx for the answer. this option i already found. it would be interresting where the origin file/s is/are placed, to set some arguments for the starting programs.

Comment: @blabliblupp I _think_ that it searches for applications by looking at the `.desktop` files. Those files are located in two directories: mostly in `/usr/share/applications`, but some of them are in `~/.local/share/applications`. Note that this is not the directory where these programs are stored, just the place where `.desktop` files get stored. Those files are used to quickly execute terminal commands (which is how you start applications in Linux) and the content of those files are also shown in the Application launcher.

Comment: @blabliblupp I've completed my answer, take a look. It should now have all informations you asked for.