# Best place to store xrandr settings?

Tags: release-loki, display, graphics

I'm using a dual monitor setup for my PC. However, since my other display is smaller, I adjusted its DPI/Size using the tutorial below: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Side_display

I got it working. However, each time I reboot it resets my xrand commands. So I just want to ask where do you suggest to place my xrand command for my displays?

If you're curious the command is given below:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --scale 2x2 --pos 0x0 --output eDP1 --auto --scale 1.5x1.5 --pos 3840x540
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- Using the GUI:

  1. Go to *System Settings* > *Applications* > *Startup*
  2. Click the + button
  3. Type in the xrandr command complete with its arguments
- Creating a `.desktop` file and adding it to autostart:

  1. You can make a `.desktop` file containing the command as an `Exec` key with something like this:

     `[Desktop Entry]
     Version=1.0
     Type=Application
     Name=XrandrStartup
     GenericName=XrandrStartup
     Comment=Xrandr config startup script
     Icon=preferences-system
     Categories=Settings;
     Exec=xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --scale 2x2 --pos 0x0 --output eDP1 --auto --scale 1.5x1.5 --pos 3840x540
     TryExec=xrandr
     Terminal=false
     X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`
  2. Save it on `~/.config/autostart`

---

*Based on [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1302/686)*

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to a file called ~/.bash_profile which fires when you log in. The issue with automating it is that it might misbehave if you aren't always in this setup, and also it'll run every time you open a shell.

I just leave mine in ~/dual.sh and run:

```
sh ~/dual.sh
```

Also, occasionally monitor commands have caused things to crash, so automatically running will potentially make troubleshooting more annoying.

It might be possible to create a system startup script, however then you'll probably want to write a more comprehensive script, and I think you need to run these settings after desktop has loaded.